# Active dataProvider

Tags: yii2, pagination

Здравствуйте можно ли на AciveDataProvidere отключит или убрать пагинатсую.
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Можно.

```
"pagination" => false
```

Если объект уже создан, то:

```
$provider->setPagination(false);
```

Comment: Ага спасибо решенно